# Why does this print everything on one line? I want each list to print one it's own line separated by a '|'

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

```
lcolhead = ['ID', 'Name', 'Email']
lrow1 = [1, 'Jane Doe', 'janedoe@doemail.com']
lrow2 = [2, 'Jake Doe', 'jakedoe@doemail.com']
lrow3 = [3, 'Jane Fox', 'janefox@foxmail.com']

ltable1 = [lcolhead, lrow1, lrow2, lrow3]

for row  in ltable1:
    for item in row:
        print(item, end=' | ')
```

output is each value on a single line separated by ' | '

```
ID | Name | Email | 1 | Jane Doe | janedoe@doemail.com | 2 | John Doe | johndoe@doemail.com...
```

I want it to print:

```
ID | Name | Email |
1 | Jane Doe | janedoe@doemail.com |
2 | John Doe | johndoe@doemail.com |
```

storing the column headers as a list as well as the row values in a list of lists but cannot figure out why it prints everything to a single line.

Comment: You manually changed the default new line by `end=' | '` so why would you expect new lines?

Comment: Just add `print('\n')` wherever appropriate, e.g. after the inner `for` loop.

Comment: The class exercise showed the end=' | ' in the examples, then asked for the output to have that formatting. I'm a newb so I honestly don't know anything.

Answer (score 1):

Using your solution, adding a simple `print()` statement in the outer loop fixes it:

```
lcolhead = ['ID', 'Name', 'Email']
lrow1 = [1, 'Jane Doe', 'janedoe@doemail.com']
lrow2 = [2, 'Jake Doe', 'jakedoe@doemail.com']
lrow3 = [3, 'Jane Fox', 'janefox@foxmail.com']

ltable1 = [lcolhead, lrow1, lrow2, lrow3]

for row in ltable1:
    for item in row:
        print(item, end=' | ')
    print()  # printing nothing, followed by default end='\n'
```

To other programmers that may be a confusing use of `end` though, so perhaps a better solution would be this:

```
for row in ltable1:
    print(' | '.join(map(str, row)) + ' | ')
```

This turns everything in `row` into a string with `map(str, ..)` and then joins those strings together with `|`, adding a `' | '` at the end as well, for the same result (because no `end` is specified, it defaults to `\n` here).

The result in either case:

```
ID | Name | Email | 
1 | Jane Doe | janedoe@doemail.com | 
2 | Jake Doe | jakedoe@doemail.com | 
3 | Jane Fox | janefox@foxmail.com |
```

Of course, if you don't even need that dangling `' | '`, you can just:

```
for row in ltable1:
    print(' | '.join(map(str, row)))
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Odd that they ask for this formatting in the output but didn't cover it in my class examples.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel your question was answered, consider clicking the checkmark next to the answer you accept, so that your question no longer appears as unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

```
for row  in ltable1:
    print( " | ".join( row) + " | ")
```

But I'm questioning the utility of the last vertical bar.

Comment: This won't work, since the first element of `row` is an integer, which `.join()` won't like. Just like when posting a question, you should always run your code before posting, to make sure it actually behaves as expected.